# HTML CSS Обтекание fixed блока

Tags: css, html5

Есть такой код CSS:

```css
/* Wrapper */

    #wrapper {
        display: -moz-flex;
        display: -webkit-flex;
        display: -ms-flex;
        display: flex;
        -moz-flex-direction: row-reverse;
        -webkit-flex-direction: row-reverse;
        -ms-flex-direction: row-reverse;
        flex-direction: row-reverse;
        min-height: 100vh;
    }

    #main {
        -moz-flex-grow: 1;
        -webkit-flex-grow: 1;
        -ms-flex-grow: 1;
        flex-grow: 1;
        -moz-flex-shrink: 1;
        -webkit-flex-shrink: 1;
        -ms-flex-shrink: 1;
        flex-shrink: 1;
        width: 100%;
    }

        #main > .inner {
            padding: 0 6em 0.1em 6em ;
            margin: 0 auto;
            max-width: 110em;
        }

            #main > .inner > section {
                padding: 6em 0 4em 0 ;
                border-top: solid 2px rgba(210, 215, 217, 0.75);
            }

                #main > .inner > section:first-of-type {
                    border-top: 0 !important;
                }

#sidebar {
        -moz-flex-grow: 0;
        -webkit-flex-grow: 0;
        -ms-flex-grow: 0;
        flex-grow: 0;
        -moz-flex-shrink: 0;
        -webkit-flex-shrink: 0;
        -ms-flex-shrink: 0;
        flex-shrink: 0;
        -moz-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
        -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
        -ms-transition: margin-left 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
        transition: margin-left 0.5s ease, box-shadow 0.5s ease;
        background-color: #f5f6f7;
        font-size: 0.9em;
        position: relative;
        width: 26em;
    }
```

И такой код HTML

```html
<div id="wrapper">
                    <div id="main">
                        <div class="inner">
[...]
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div id="sidebar">
                        <div class="inner">
[...]
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
```

Вопрос в том, как так грамотно сделать что бы main был не подвижным и обтекался sidebar'ом с левой стороны? Ибо когда я main'у даю position: fixed он начинает обтекаться, но уже с правой стороны и немного заплывает в фон за sidebar.

Comment: У вас #wrapper недописан в CSS-коде

Comment: исправил, код не мой